# Automatize injection filtering

Tags: php, filter, code-injection

I have several PHP pages where i filter manually the POST and GET input to prevent injection.Is there a way to filter with *mysql_real_escape_string* every POST and GET my page recives automatically?

Comment: You could just apply `real_escape_string` to the entire superglobals (you'd have to loop through them), but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't work with these superglobals directly. You should instead have an object fetch specific items for you, and that object could filter the data to fit your heart's desire.

Comment: Btw, escaping your data anywhere but right when it's meant to go into the database is bad programming. You may want to use these values somewhere throughout your code, and they should be untampered with. To protect against SQL injection, look into prepared statements.

Comment: @Mansfield Should I loop and asign the value filtered to new variables? In that case, how can i loop through all the values?

Comment: @Marcel With the object fecth system, is there a way to fetch automatically every variable sent?

Comment: @user1876542 You could loop and re-assign each item to the superglobal. But **I wouldn't recommend doing this**. Better to just escape when you're using the data in the query, or better yet use parameterized queries.

Comment: @Mansfield Ok thx , and why it is not recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hoi user11876542,

what about array_map("YOUR_FUNCTION",$_POST) ?

e.g.

```
$post = array_map('strip_tags',$_POST);
```